# Select most frequent value and count using LINQ and assign to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select the top five most frequent values and their count in my table and return them in a Dictionary. I'm able to get the values in sql:

```
SELECT top 5 
    SR_Status,
    COUNT(SR_Status) AS 'value_count'
FROM     
    ServiceRequests
GROUP BY 
    SR_Status
ORDER BY 
    'value_count' DESC;
```

How to convert to linq and assign to  Dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not specify if you are using Linq2Sql or Linq2Objects, so, let's just assume linq then. Try something like this (*see the comments for each line*):

```
var result = (from s in ServiceRequests // define the data source
             group s by s.SR_Status into g  // group all items by status
             orderby g.Count() descending // order by count descending
             select new { g.Key, Total = g.Count() }) // cast the output
             .Take(5) // take just 5 items
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Total); // cast to dictionary
```

*Obs: I didn't test it.*

Comment: A list is not a dictionary

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework and have an EntitySet named ServiceRequests and all the properties names are the same as the column names:

```
var result = context.ServiceRequests.GroupBy(sr => sr.SR_Status)
    .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Count)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```